# When the cursor leaves the input box #select-or-enter-category, this code checks whether the given input exists in the dropdown or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code I use for showing a warning message:

```
<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
    <div>
      <div class="form-line focus">
        <span class="category-status" style="color: red;">
          This entered category is not found in the category list.<br> 
          Press button on the right to save this new category.
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, I have another code use for typeahead dropdown:

```
<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-2">
    <div class="form-group form-float">
      <div class="form-line focus">
        <input type="hidden" id="cat-id" name="category_id" value="">
        <input type="text" id="select-or-enter-category" name="category" data-provide="typeahead" 
        placeholder="Enter/Select a category" value="" required="required" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <button type="button" id="save-category" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" 
      class="btn btn-warning" data-original-title="Save this input as New Category">
        <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-bookmark-o" style="display: inline;"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is my javascript/jquery code:
When the user types keyword in an input box `#select-or-enter-category`,
this javascript code will give a dropdown as typeahead for the given keyword.

```
/**
 * Autocomplete for category - ADD TASK MODAL
 * @return {[type]} [description]
 */
$(document).ready(function(){
  axios_get('/axiosCategory', function(data) {
    var cat    = [];
    var $input = $("#select-or-enter-category");
    let temp;

    data.forEach(function(item) {
      temp = {
        id: item.id,
        name: item.categoryName
      }
      cat.push(temp);
    });

    $input.typeahead({
      source: cat,
      autoSelect: true
    });

    $input.change(function() {
      // console.log($input);
      var current = $input.typeahead("getActive");
      if (current) {
        $('#cat-id').val(current.id);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

When the cursor leaves the input box `#select-or-enter-category`, this code checks whether the given input exists in the dropdown or not. If not, the warning message will show up that will ask the user to save the input as a new category.

```
/**
 * Display the message asking the user to save the
 * new category
 *
 * @return void
 */
$('#select-or-enter-category').focusout(function() {
  let val = $(this).val();

  axios_get('/axiosCategory', function(data) {
    let search = false;

    data.forEach(function(item) {
      if (val == item.categoryName) {
        search = true;
      }
    });

    if (search == false) {
      $('.category-status').removeAttr('hidden');
    } else {
      $('.category-status').attr('hidden', true);
    }
  });
});
```

Then problem is that when the user clicks an item from the dropdown using the mouse, the error message shows up which is not what I want to happen.

I want the error message to show up only when the cursor actually leaves the input box `#select-or-enter-category`.

But if the user only uses keyboard for choosing an item from the dropdown and enter it, there is no problem.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  axios_get('/axiosCategory', function(data) {
    dataGlobal = data;

    var cat    = [];
    var $input = $("#select-or-enter-category");
    let temp;

    data.forEach(function(item) {
      temp = {
        id: item.id,
        name: item.categoryName
      }
      cat.push(temp);
    });

    $input.typeahead({
      source: cat,
      autoSelect: true
    });

    $input.change(function() {
      var current = $input.typeahead("getActive");
      if (current) {
        $('#cat-id').val(current.id);
      }
    });

    $input.focusout(function() {
      let val     = $('#select-or-enter-category').val();
      let current = $input.typeahead("getActive");
      let search  = false;
      let str     = current.name.substring(0,val.length);

      if (str == val) {
        val = current.name;
      }

      dataGlobal.forEach(function(item) {
        if (val == item.categoryName) {
          search = true;
        }
      });

      if (search == false) {
        $('#category-status').removeAttr('hidden');

      } else {
        $('#category-status').attr('hidden', 'hidden');
      }
    });
  });
});
```